# Clipping area correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

Trying to think about this [intersection of functions or polygon tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305715/intersection-of-functions-or-polygon-tikz/305761#305761)  I arrived to my long standing question - how to clip and fill area correctly? Usin tkz-fct
MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=20,ymin=-1,ymax=20]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid

\tkzFct[thick, red, domain=-1:20]{29-6*\x}
\tkzFct[thick, green, domain=-1:20]{4.8-0.2*\x}
\tkzFct[thick, blue, domain=-1:6]{(16-4*\x)/2}

\clip (1.5,20) --   (4.2,3.9) -- (20,0.8) -- (20,20)-- cycle;
\fill[blue!20,fill opacity=.7] (1.5,0) rectangle (20,20);

%\clip (0,8) --  (4,0) --  (4.8,0) --  (1.5,20) -- (0,20)-- cycle;
%\fill[red!20,fill opacity=.7] (0,0) rectangle (5,20);

%\clip (4,0) --(1.8,4.45) --  (20,0.8)-- (20,0) -- cycle;
%\fill[green!20,fill opacity=.7] (1.8,0) rectangle (20,20);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: region]
If one open comments the picture becomes invalid. How I can use `\clip` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\clip` will affect everything after it, to limit its effect place it in a `scope` environment along with the things that should be clipped.

In this case the filling will partially cover the plotted lines, to fix that simply move the `\tkzFct` lines to the end of the diagram.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=20,ymin=-1,ymax=20]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid

\begin{scope}
\clip (1.5,20) --   (4.2,3.9) -- (20,0.8) -- (20,20)-- cycle;
\fill[blue!20,fill opacity=.7] (1.5,0) rectangle (20,20);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,8) --  (4,0) --  (4.8,0) --  (1.5,20) -- (0,20)-- cycle;
\fill[red!20,fill opacity=.7] (0,0) rectangle (5,20);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip (4,0) --(1.8,4.45) --  (20,0.8)-- (20,0) -- cycle;
\fill[green!20,fill opacity=.7] (1.8,0) rectangle (20,20);
\end{scope}

\tkzFct[thick, red, domain=-1:20]{29-6*\x}
\tkzFct[thick, green, domain=-1:20]{4.8-0.2*\x}
\tkzFct[thick, blue, domain=-1:6]{(16-4*\x)/2}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Understand you, thanks. Another question arises - lines drawn before cliping became pale. How one can re-construct them?

Comment: @OlgaK That's because the filling somewhat covers the lines, just move the plotting commands to the end.